# Split a number by equal parts in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Can anyone help me by splitting a number into equal parts in bash script?

input:

- n=1000
- divide_by=4

output

- 250,500,700,1000

Comment: Where specifically are you stuck at: Have you got the formula to do it? Do you know how to make a loop in Bash?

Comment: Nope. Iam a beginner to linux. Consider my n = 1000 and divide_by = 4. Then i have a array of x values. Now my bash script should say how many values between 0 to 250, 250 to 500, 500 to 750 and 750 to 1000

Comment: What output do you expect for n=1000 and divide_by=6?

Comment: Edit your question. If you look for what you say in your comment, the output is not the same as in your question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We really need a *"Givez mez the codez"* Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

You can use arithmetic in bash, e.g. `incr=$((1000 / 4))` and then you can produce a sequence 250, 500, 750, 1000 by `for i in $(seq ${incr} ${incr} 1000)` e.g.

Answer (score 0):

Use arithmetic expressions to do the math, and a loop to print the sequence.

```
#! /bin/bash
number=$1
divide_by=$2

(( part = number / divide_by ))
result=$part

while (( result <= number )) ; do
    printf '%d ' $result
    (( result += part ))
done
echo
```

Note that for numbers with non-zero remainder (e.g. 1000 and 6), the sequence doesn't end in the initial number, but in `number - remainder`.